# Mysql/PHP code is returning all rows except first and last

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am having a time tryng to pull ALL records out of a database. For example I have the following

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `plant_info` ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, 50") or die(mysql_error());
// Variables to pull from the database
// I know the line below is the culprit now, so i must change the code below correct? ///
$returneddata = mysql_fetch_array($result);
///////////////////////////////////////////
$LatinName = $returneddata['Latin_Name'];
$CommonName = $returneddata['Common_Name'];
$Category = $returneddata['Category'];
$Type = $returneddata['Type'];
$Fruit = $returneddata['Fruit'];
$Flower = $returneddata['Flower'];
$MinHeight = $returneddata['Min_Height'];
$MaxHeight = $returneddata['Max_Height'];
$MinWidth = $returneddata['Min_Width'];
$MaxWidth = $returneddata['Max_Width'];
$Exposure = $returneddata['Exposure'];
$Comments = $returneddata['Comments'];
$SoilType = $returneddata['Soil_Type'];
$Zone = $returneddata['Zone'];
$PotSize = $returneddata['Pot_Size'];
$CostPrice = $returneddata['Cost_Price'];
$RetailPrice = $returneddata['Retail_Price'];
$ImageName = $returneddata['Image_Name'];
$ImageNameThumb = $returneddata['Image_Name_Thumb'];
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); echo "$num_rows Rows\n";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


echo "                           <tr>
                            <td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#000000\">
                                <p><img src=\"$row[Image_Name]\" style=\"width:120px;height:auto;\"></p>
                            </td>
                            <td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#90c084\">
                                <p>$row[Latin_Name]</p>
                            </td>
                            <td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#90c084\">
                                <p>$row[Common_Name]</p>
                            </td>
                            <td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#90c084\">
                                <p>$row[Category]</p>
                            </td>
                            <td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#90c084\">
                                <p>$row[Type]</p>
                            </td>

                            <td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#90c084\">
                                <p>$row[Flower]</p>

                            </td>
                            <td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#90c084\">
                               <p>$row[Comments]</p>
                            </td>

                            </td>
                            <td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#90c084\">
                               <p><a href=\"editplant.php?get=$row[id]\">Edit</a></p>
                               <p><a href =\"print_sign_div.php?get=$row[id]\">Print</a></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

";
}
```

The issue i have is that it will pull all the records except for the first one. Every other record shows, there are only 5 records currently.

I am missing something silly I know it. I looked through questions and could not find the answer. Thanks

Comment: If there are only 5 records, can you paste your DB for us?

Comment: I had that Norse, same thing :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean Keaner.  Try adding in `$count = mysql_num_rows($result); print "Count is $count";` Before you do any of your looping to verify mysql is grabbing the number of rows you're expecting.  If you can update the above with your full code you're now using (as well as a dump of "SELECT * from plant_info", that would help people be able to help you

Comment: So yep I'm an idiot, I don't even need the 

$Variable = $returneddata['column_name'];

In this page. sorry guys, but thanks for all the help. need sleep much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be because you're calling the `mysql_fetch_array` command twice.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

You only need to declare `mysql_fetch_array` once, which is inside the `while` parameter.

This should be your code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `plant_info` ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, 30");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo "                           <tr>
                            <td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#000000\">
                                <p><img src=\"$row[Image_Name]\" style=\"width:120px;height:auto;\"></p>
                            </td>
                            <td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#90c084\">
                                <p>$row[Latin_Name]</p>
                            </td>
                            <td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#90c084\">
                                <p>$row[Common_Name]</p>
                            </td>
                            <td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#90c084\">
                                <p>$row[Category]</p>
                            </td>
                            <td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#90c084\">
                                <p>$row[Type]</p>
                            </td>

                            <td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#90c084\">
                                <p>$row[Flower]</p>

                            </td>
                            <td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#90c084\">
                               <p>$row[Comments]</p>
                            </td>

                            </td>
                            <td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#90c084\">
                               <p><a href=\"editplant.php?get=$row[id]\">Edit</a></p>
                               <p><a href =\"print_sign_div.php?get=$row[id]\">Print</a></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

";
}
```

Comment: Cal's answer below got me all but the very first result. 

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); echo "$num_rows Rows\n";

Gives me "5"

Comment: Cal's suggestion is the correct syntax. It should be giving you all your results unless you're implementing it wrong. I'll update my answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't post valid/all your PHP - there's no `mysql_query()` call.

```
SELECT * FROM `plant_info` ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, 30
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

line 2 there fetches a row and does nothing with it anyway, throwing away the first row. try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `plant_info` ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, 30");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

After your question update, it looks like you want to pull out info from the first row, then loop over all the rows. Here's a way to do that:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `plant_info` ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, 30");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}

$row = $rows[0];
$LatinName = $returneddata['Latin_Name'];
...

foreach ($rows as $row){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me 4 out of my 5 to return. Only one missing now is the very first one.

Comment: Can you update your questions to show your full code? You should reduce the example code as much as possible to isolate the issue - just echo one line in each loop. The less code you have, the easier it is to spot the problem!

Comment: I also have one of these in there

$returneddata = mysql_fetch_array($result);

Which was taking my first result, but i use this to display data like so:

$LatinName = $returneddata['Latin_Name'];

hmmmm

Comment: you *must* post all your code in the question. we can't guess what it looks like!

Comment: come on cal your not a psychic? :). I got it though thanks, see comment above.